# Why are new users not made to visit the Tour page before being able to post?

Tags: feature-request

As a moderator on Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange site a fair amount of my time is spent commenting on posts by new users that they should visit the Tour page to get a better understanding of how the site works.

Reasons for this most commonly include a question being posted in the answer section or a question is posted that is too broad or off-topic. It gets to be quite tiresome to post the same comment along the lines of:

> Hello and welcome to the site. Your question is too broad for the Q&A
>   format of the site. I would recommend you take the
>   [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how the
>   site works.

My thought is some of this hassle could be cut out if a new user had to visit the Tour page before being able to post. A counter argument to that would be they'll simply scroll quickly through to the bottom of the page without reading anything. An alternative solution could be you have to watch a short 30 second video explaining how a Stack Exchange site works before being allowed post anything.

I prefer the second option because people are lazy and watching a 30 second video isn't as much hassle. Of course there will be people who won't pay attention, but that solution might see a higher success rate over forcing someone to read a Tour page.

In either solution the Tour page would still exist in its current format. Also if you join another Stack Exchange site, and you already have 200 rep on a site, you wouldn't have to look through the Tour page/watch a video.

I'm not saying this is going to completely eliminate the problem that sites like Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange face where there is a large proportion of new users compared to active high rep users. But it could help to reduce the issue.

Comment: Well, they did pass [/ask/advice](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) and checked the box at the end, so ...

Comment: The tour doesn’t really include anything that’d stop those kinds of posts

Comment: There were even [better proposals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process) already.

Answer (score 6):

**New users are already taken to the tour when registering**. I just verified this myself, and indeed, upon completing sign up, you get taken straight to the tour.

They aren't, however, compelled to get the 'Informed' badge, and can just skip past the tour and go straight to asking/answering (as, evidently, so many users do).

Unregistered users (who just enter an email after clicking 'Ask Question') won't be shown the tour if they ask a question (they get no additional guidance at all), and it appears that [/ask/advice](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) **isn't** shown to users either way on RPi.

With answers, users are shown a popup that says:

> Thanks for contributing an answer to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange!
>
> - Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!
>
> But avoid …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
>
> To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

... even if they're unregistered.

---

So, in a way, the tour is already shown, but there are many ways that you can join that would lead to you not seeing it. Users with the association bonus also aren't shown the tour, as you'd expect. Ultimately, it seems that many people skip past it, just like any other terms and conditions that users don't want to read.

Comment: Wait, what .... /ask/advice isn't shown? That's a real waste then.

Comment: @rene, it definitely is for Stack Overflow, but I don't think that happens for other SE sites like RPi.